# Вывод модуля средствами php с привязкой к пунтам меню Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

Существует множество вариантов вывода модулей Joomla. Начиная от loadposition заканчивая различными вариантами реализации через php

Но одним из недостатков является то, что такие способы не учитывают параметры привязки модуля к пунктам меню.

Например я вывожу модуль в шаблоне компонента

```
<?php 
    $module_position = 'позиция модуля';
    $modules =& JModuleHelper::getModules($module_position);
    foreach ($modules as $module){
     $my_module = JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
    }
?>
```

В таком случае игнорируются привязки модуля к пунктам меню и модуль выводится на всех страницах которые используют данный шаблон компонента

Подскажите, как реализовать при таком способе вывода возможность отображения модуля еще и в соответствии с привязкой к пунктам меню в админпанели?

Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно тогда импортировать настройки каждого модуля, получать список ItemId и далее сверять уже текущий пункт с настройками - in_array().